# Liquibase 3.3.2, running diff in report mode, how to reorder displayed output

Tags: liquibase

I am running liquibase diff command against Oracle 12c database and local repo. I get nice output but it will require manual manipulation to make it usable for me.

Especially "Unexpected Columns" section, the columns listed are tablename.columnname format, but they are sorted by column_name. Is it possible to have those sorted by table_name then column_name and optionally specify datatype, precision etc? I have not yet tested but i suspect same is true for "Changed Columns" section as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not using the command line tool but by using the SDK you can. Check http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/Liquibase.html#diff(liquibase.database.Database, liquibase.database.Database, liquibase.diff.compare.CompareControl)

Comment: Thanks, i don't much speak Java, so guess this is difficult at this moment.